# Importing files from an "outside" folder

Tags: solidity, solc, import

I am trying to import files from a relative path outside of my Truffle-project folder:

```
import '../../../common/solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/BurnableToken.sol';
import '../../../common/solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/MintableToken.sol';
```

But when I compile with `solc.exe`, I get the error `File outside of allowed directories`.

BTW, I have no idea how come `solc.exe` has any knowledge of my Truffle-project folder.

In any case, checking [the docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/layout-of-source-files.html#use-in-actual-compilers), I found the following related information:

> Note that solc only allows you to include files from certain directories: They have to be in the directory (or subdirectory) of one of the explicitly specified source files or in the directory (or subdirectory) of a remapping target. If you want to allow direct absolute includes, just add the remapping =/.

But I fail to understand the meaning of `just add the remapping =/`.

Can anybody please shed some light on this statement?

How exactly can I import those two files correctly?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi: Yes I did. Don't "mess with the system", just follow Truffle project structure, i.e., all contracts under `contracts` folder, all tests under `test` folder, etc.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi: Yes, you need to run `solc` from a path which is a parent of all the source files in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, the only workaround I have found is to pass the `..=..` argument to solc, so it will correctly interpret the paths.

So my layout is:

```
├── artifacts
├── contr
│   └── A.sol
└── somedir
    └── B.sol
```

contracts/A.sol:

```
...
import "../somedir/B.sol";
...
```

And I run solc from the root dir in the following way:

```
solc --abi --bin contr/A.sol -o artifacts --overwrite ..=..
```